# Get stats of a specific Django memcached cache

Tags: python, django, debugging, caching, memcached

I can get the stats for a Memcached server in Python like this:

```
import memcache
host = memcache._Host('127.0.0.1:11211')
host.connect()
host.send_cmd('stats')
stats = {}
while 1:
    line = host.readline().split(None, 2)
    if line[0] == "END": break
    stat, key, value = line
    try:
        value = int(value)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    stats[key] = value
host.close_socket()
print stats
```

Using several caches in Django, how do I get the stats for a *specific* one, e.g. the "store" cache in this configuration:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': { 'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache', 'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211', 'OPTIONS': { 'MAX_ENTRIES': 4000 } },
    'store': { 'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache', 'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211', 'OPTIONS': { 'MAX_ENTRIES': 1000 } },
}
```

I'd like to find out if MAX_ENTRIES is large enough for our purpose. So I need to know how many items are currently in the "default" cache and in the "stored" cache.

UPDATE: AFAICS, Memcached does not support MAX_ENTRIES and the different "cache names" are only used for Django's cache prefixs. Likely, there's no different cache units inside Memcached.